# Chomsky hierarchy - Type-1 context-sensitive languages

Tags: theory, context-sensitive-grammar, chomsky-hierarchy

I try to unterstand the Chomsky hierarchy with the different levels.

I checked some examples and here is one I don't really understand. Maybe someone knows why this one is not a context-sensitive language:

```
S → aA 
A → aA | ε
B → bA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar `G` that you provide is, beyond any doubt, context free (each rule has one non-terminal in the LHS and a string of terminals and non-terminals in the RHS).  Therefore, the language `L` that it generates is context free.  Therefore, as the category of context-free languages is a proper subset of that of context-sensitive languages, **language `L` is context sensitive**.  (I don't know where you read that language `L` is not context sensitive.  Either you misread this or what you read is simply wrong.)

I will make a guess about the reason of this confusion.  Let us suppose that you had claimed that **grammar** `G` (not **language** `L`) is not context sensitive.  Now, perhaps curiously enough, if a language is context sensitive this does not mean that **all grammars** producing this language are context sensitive (and the same is true for the other categories as well, except of course the unrestricted one).  If a language is context sensitive, this means that **there is** a context-sensitive grammar producing it.  So, even if `L` is context sensitive, this does not necessarily mean that `G` is also context sensitive.

It would however be weird if `G`, a context-free grammar, were not context sensitive.  Whether this is or is not true depends on your exact definition of a context-sensitive grammar.  As you can read, e.g., in the [related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar), there are at least two alternative definitions for context-sensitive grammars:

1. A grammar where all rules are of the form αAβ → αγβ, where A is a non-terminal symbol and α, β, γ are strings of terminals and non-terminals.
2. A grammar where all rules are of the form α → β, where α and β are strings of terminals and non-terminals, but the length of α is not larger than the length of β.  As an exception, there can be a rule S → ε for the start symbol S (which would otherwise be forbidden).

According to definition 1, grammar `G` is context sensitive (the context strings α and β being trivially empty).  According to definition 2, however, grammar `G` is not, because of the empty production rule for non-terminal A, which is not the start symbol.

It is however possible to provide an equivalent grammar `G'`, which is context sensitive according to both definitions and produces the same language `L`.  One such grammar can be constructed as follows:

A produces strings of zero or more "a".  We can replace its definition by:

```
A → A' | ε
A' → a | aA'
```

where A' produces strings of one or more "a".  Notice that the rules for A are not recursive.  We can substitute the productions for A in the rules for S and B and then eliminate the non-terminal A.  This gives us:

```
S → aA' | a
A' → a | aA'
B → bA' | b
```

This grammar (which can be further simplified by noticing that A' and S produce the same language) is context sensitive according to both definitions above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I had some notes from a class in university and probably I just took some wrong notes.